# Describe the span of vectors geometrically

Tags: linear-algebra

I've filled in my answers here.

[image: I've filled in my answers here.]

Unfortunately it won't tell me which one(s) are incorrect. Here is my logic for each of the answers:

a) The two vectors are linearly dependent, so the span is a line. I think the direction vector is any one of the two vectors since they are scalar multiples of each other?

b) Again, the two vectors are linearly dependent so the span is a line. The zero vector does not have a direction, so the direction vector is (3, 4).

c) The vectors are linearly independent so the span is a plane. Since the vectors are linearly independent, both vectors are direction vectors.

d) The three vectors are linearly dependent, but two vectors taken together are linearly independent, so the span is a plane. I think any two of the vectors can be the direction vectors since they span the plane?

Any help would be appreciated. I'm just not sure where I am going wrong or right.

Comment: Hi, your answers look good to me.

Comment: All your answers are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I thought I was losing my mind there! Guess the grading software is just wonky.